# rand() not so random in perl

Tags: perl, random

I have a Perl script that gives me a 50 character string of random numbers, letters and some special characters.  I am inputting them in a database.  Now, given the length of the string and the amount of characters, I wouldn't think that duplicates would be easily created.

Here's the nifty nugget of code that creates the string:

```
my $random_id='';
my @c = ( "A" .. "Z", "a" .. "z", 0 .. 9, qw(! @ $ % ^ & *) );
$random_id = join '', map $c[rand @c] , 1 .. 50;
```

It produces strings like:

> C1Qt8L7E7QUD%lkxnh9yjZ2njF0iMj!1o^4DmTbVNhQB9%dke@

The problem is it will duplicate an exact string every once and a while among unique ones, and more than once on some strings.  And this is out of say 20 strings.  It's bizarre.  I can work around it and find a solution... but this perplexes me a bit.  Would like to know why.  Anybody have an idea?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to use srand to seed the random number generator otherwise it will generate the same number series.

http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/srand.html

Edit:

According to the doc atthe url, if the perl version is before 5.004 then it won't automatically call that function. So check the perl version you're running under.

Comment: Woops... didn't get to answer.  If I change rand() to srand() it now outputs purely BBBBBBBBBBB.. every time.  : /

Comment: actually, if I call srand() by itself before rand() it seems to do the trick.  again thanks for the post.

Comment: @Xiquid: Minor and largely irrelevant detail, but I suspect that you mean you're using Perl 5.10 (which came after 5.9 and before 5.11) rather than 5.1 (which would be truly ancient, released in 1995 as Perl 5.001) - the version numbers are not proper decimals. Although, if you were on 5.001, I guess that would explain `rand` not automatically seeding the first time it's called...

Comment: @Xiquid - yes, you just need to call srand() once at the start of the script to initialise the random number generator, then use rand() as normally from then on.

Comment: @Dave, hi dave!  Thanks for your response.  I am in fact using v5.10.0 as perl -v

Answer (score 3):

you can also see [String::Random](http://search.cpan.org/~steve/String-Random-0.20/Random.pm) - for generating random strings based on a pattern.

Comment: also something like Data::UUID (http://search.cpan.org/dist/Data-UUID/) may be appropriate if the strings are being used in a database (e.g. as persistent unique primary keys)

Comment: @plusplus But that's opening the can of worms: "Should a UUID [ever] be a primary key?" :-)

Answer (score 3):

For GOOD random numbers, consider using [Math::Random::MT](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Math%3a%3aRandom%3a%3aMT).